# Third party library without Proguard rules causing Proguard error

Tags: java, android, android-proguard

I am receiving the following error when trying to release an obfuscated version using proguard:

> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':MyApp:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForMyAppRelease'.
>     java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

Updated all my libraries to the latest version and I'm using gradle 2.0.0.

Comment: Is this the only messege you get? Try verbose proguard output and there should be some warning that you need to address.

Answer (score 0):

I saw these errors too, while uploading my first app.See if this works

```
-dontwarn <package of the class giving error>.**
```

Write it in your proguard-rules.pro